# SQL change the searched query based on a multiple result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck, I would like to query based on multiple results, and loop until there are no more results..

```
USE Production
DECLARE @job VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @drawing VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @job = job.job , @drawing = job.Drawing
FROM Production.dbo.Job 
WHERE Job = 'T361322'
PRINT @job
PRINT @Drawing
```

The results I get are the T361322 and then the drawing, which I want to move to the job search to find other drawings until there are no further results.
so use Set?

Comment: So the drawing field has data that matches the job field? Sounds like a job for a recursive CTE.

Comment: what's the end goal here? What would the expected results look like? This doesn't make sense to me currently.

Comment: seconding scsiomn, it would help if we knew what your end goal was. There is a simpler way than my answer to retrieve the data you want if your only goal is to view it.

Comment: of the 2 colums A and B. If I search for an item in Colum A it may or may not return nested results from colum B. I then want to move the results from B to A and loop the search again, which may also return different results in colum B.

Comment: Think about it as a Car being the job. well that car will have multiple drwaings or plans, one for the engine, 1 for the transmission, ect and I want to then turn the engine into a job and see what new drwaings I need for that? water pump, starter drawing ect. that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a loop to do this is not ideal inside `SQL Server`. You may instead try something like this.

```
USE Production 
GO 
DECLARE @table TABLE ( job VARCHAR(10) , drawing VARCHAR(10) ) 

INSERT INTO @table (job , drawing) 
SELECT job.job , job.drawing 
FROM Production.dbo.Job 
WHERE Job = 'TC361322'

SELECT * FROM @table;
```

Comment: Agree with your comment, but in this case, the table variable is pointless and they should just select from `Production.dbo.Job `

Comment: Yes, if all he wanted was the list then I would agree with you. I assume he is using the variables somewhere else. Like further down in a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, let me clarify a bit. the job and can be a drawing and vs versa. so If I searched for the above example, 361322 I'l get a drawing with 361333. What I want to is then search for the drawing 361333 as the job. which in turn returns 2 drawings, 331089 and 320482 and In turn I'd like to search for 331089 and 320482 as the job. the results are nested..so maybe a loop?

Comment: I almost got this from SSRS. as the following.

Comment: SELECT
  Material_Req.Material
  ,Material_Req.Material_OID
  ,Job.Job AS [Job.job]
 , Material.Job AS Template
FROM
Job INNER JOIN Material_Req 
  ON Job.Job = Material_Req.Job INNER JOIN Material 
  ON Material_Req.Material = Material.Material LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location 
  ON Material_Req.Material = Material_Location.Material

WHERE
  Material_Req.Job = @Job

Comment: Why don't you add that previous comment to your question, then we can edit it to make it more readable.